# Values of getrefcount

Tags: python

I have code, which I am trying to infer reference count of an object with respect to their memory location. What I understand is a variable is referred by it's memory address which basically gives us the value which is passed to it. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Now, what I am getting is confusing me, here is the code with output below :

```
  >>> import sys
  >>> a = [1,2,3]
  >>> id(a)
  1920192000520
  >>> sys.getrefcount(a)
  8
  >>> b = a
  >>> b
  [1, 2, 3]
  >>> sys.getrefcount(b)
  23
```

I have invoked these variables once (i.e there is no previous declaration or no other reference), so not sure why there are higher values like 8, 23 for same object in the memory.

Although I see the value is correct when I am passing the actual memory id, I get the value as 1

```
 >>> sys.getrefcount(id(a))
 1
 >>> sys.getrefcount(id(b))
 1
```

Why there is a difference, can someone please shed light on this concept?

Thanks much.

Comment: Note that there's no inherent meaning to `sys.getrefcount(id(a))`. It gives you the refcount of some random numeric value, not of the object at the memory address expressed by the value returned by `id`…

Comment: Are you running your code in a REPL? Interactive prompts can have a lot going on behind the scenes. For example, it may be examining your variables for diagnostic purposes. Try running your code using regular python.exe and you may get more sensible numbers.

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook, so the behavior differs in there too ?